# storing shared paths in mysql using file input in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to use a input type=file for the user to select the path from a shared network drive in php web app. I am just using this to get the file name and not doing anything with the selected file. Now, I am storing this path in the mysql database. I am not sure why, but it gets stored as '

say for example, if the path contains 
`\\\\filsrv\\logs\\tests`

now in the DB, the \\ get stripped off and the part '\t' gets replaced to 'tab' . I do not know why is this happenening. The data type that is used in the MYSQL db is varchar. Can anyone explain me how do I get this path stored correctly?

Comment: Can you show us some code? How is the data inserted into the DB? I suspect that you are missing a call to `mysql_escape_string`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it with addslashes to add extra bit of slashes to store the path correctly. Thx anyway @Ferdinand Beyer